# get file name after $config['encrypt_name'] in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamicmvc

You have added $ config ['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; For the upload code because some user images are called spaces and problems causing problems lifting

After uploading the file its name is changed but I try to take the file name to send it to the database
this way
$ img1 = $ _FILES ['img1'] ['name'];
But I get the original file name before changing

```
  $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
  $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size']             = 2000;
  $config['max_width']            = 1024;
  $config['max_height']           = 768;
  $config['overwrite']        = FALSE;
  $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Comment: _"You have added"_ - No, I haven't added anything?

Comment: That setting will most likely not change the name in the `$_FILES`-array. Try fetching the name using: `$this->upload->data('file_name');`. [Here's the manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data)

Comment: It worked but I have 8 photos how I get the name of each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loop trough each photo and initialize the library with the $_FILES['file_name'] this will help you

```
 $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
 $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
 $config['max_size']             = 2000;
 $config['max_width']            = 1024;
 $config['max_height']           = 768;
 $config['overwrite']        = FALSE;
 $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

 $this->load->library('upload', $config);

 $this->upload->do_upload('file_name');
 $image_uploaded = $this->upload->data();

 $filename = pathinfo($image_uploaded['full_path']);

 $insert['photo'] = $filename['basename'];

 $this->db->insert('your_table', $insert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't fall back to the `$_FILE` superglobal. Since you're using CI, stick to CI's upload wrapper

Assign the output of the upload process to a variable like this:

```
$your_variable = $this->upload->data();
```

By doing this, you get all the upload data in your newly created `$your_variable` array:

```
$your_variable['file_name'] // encrypted name
$your_variable['file_type'] // MIME type such as image/jpeg or application/pdf
$your_variable['file_path'] // self explanatory
$your_variable['raw_name'] // encrypted name without the extension
$your_variable['orig_name'] // original name
$your_variable['client_name'] // name the file had on the client's computer
$your_variable['file_ext'] // self explanatory
$your_variable['file_size'] // self explanatory. Size in Kb
$your_variable['is_image'] // 1 if yes, 0 otherwise
$your_variable['image_width'] // only for images
$your_variable['image_height'] // only for images
$your_variable['image_type'] // only for images
$your_variable['image_size_str'] // only for images
```

I'm pretty sure those are all you get as of CI 3.1.10 (but I may have forgotten a couple, if so I apologize)

You need the `['file_name']` element for your purposes. 
Going back to the `$_FILE` superglobal will not work, as CI won't modify its values